# Как удалить тестовый опубликованный App Bundle из Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

Пытаюсь удалить тестовый не активный `App Bundle` из `App Bundle Explorer` но кнопки удалить нету
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ... кажется вам нужно было перед тем как публиковать определиться.

Comment: @МихаилРебров с чем определиться ?